# Python: My x axis labels do not show, only the column header

Tags: python, pandas, axis-labels

The x-axis should be a series of dates; instead, I'm getting just the my_date header. How do I return the dates? By the way, I am visualizing the number of daily registrations for a project.

```
viz = registrations.groupby('my_date').count()[['event_type']]
viz.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's dificult to understant without seeing an example of your data frame, but is your 'my_date' column a datetime object? You could check that with a `registrations.info()`

You should see something like `my_date    4 non-null      datetime64[ns]`

If it is not a datetime64, you need to convert using:

```
registrations['my_date'] = pd.to_datetime(registrations['my_date'])
```